# Django unittest and mocking the requests module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

I am new to Mock and am writing a unit test for this function:

```
# utils.py
import requests    

def some_function(user):
    payload = {'Email': user.email}
    url = 'http://api.example.com'
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)      

    if response.status_code == 200:
       return response.json()
    else:
        return None
```

I am using [Michael Foord's Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) library as part of my unit test and am having difficulty mocking the `response.json()` to return a json structure. Here is my unit test:

```
# tests.py
from .utils import some_function

class UtilsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_function(self):
        with patch('utils.requests') as mock_requests:
            mock_requests.get.return_value.status_code = 200
            mock_requests.get.return_value.content = '{"UserId":"123456"}'
            results = some_function(self.user)
            self.assertEqual(results['UserId'], '123456')
```

I have tried numerous combinations of different mock settings after reading the docs with no luck. If I print the `results` in my unit test it always displays the following instead of the json data structure I want:

```
<MagicMock name=u'requests.get().json().__getitem__().__getitem__()' id='30315152'>
```

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Patch `json` method instead of `content`. (`content` is not used in `some_function`)

Try following code.

```
import unittest

from mock import Mock, patch

import utils

class UtilsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_function(self):
        user = self.user = Mock()
        user.email = 'user@example.com'
        with patch('utils.requests') as mock_requests:
            mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response = Mock()
            mock_response.status_code = 200
            mock_response.json.return_value = {"UserId":"123456"}
            results = utils.some_function(self.user)
            self.assertEqual(results['UserId'], '123456')
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It's now working as I had hoped.

Comment: One more assertion test I would add to you unit test would be to ensure the request.get method was called with expected parameters. Something like, `mock_get.assert_called_with('http://api.example.com', payload={'Email': self.user.email}`. This ensures that your library code is making the request call with expected parameters, which is just as important as testing the library code's return value, which is mocked.

Comment: superb answer ty

Answer (score 2):

Another pattern I like to use that is a little more reusable would be to start the patcher in your unit test's `setUp` method. It's also important to check that mock request was called  with the expected parameters:

```
class UtilsTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = Mock(id=123, email='foo@bar.com')

        patcher = patch('utils.requests.get')
        self.mock_response = Mock(status_code=200)
        self.mock_response.raise_for_status.return_value = None
        self.mock_response.json.return_value = {'UserId': self.user.id}
        self.mock_request = patcher.start()
        self.mock_request.return_value = self.mock_response

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_request.stop()

    def test_request(self):
        results = utils.some_function(self.user)

        self.assertEqual(results['UserId'], 123)

        self.mock_request.assert_called_once_with(
            'http://api.example.com'
            payload={'Email': self.user.email},
        )

    def test_bad_request(self):
        # override defaults and reassign
        self.mock_response.status_code = 500
        self.mock_request.return_value = self.mock_response
        results = utils.some_function(self.user)

        self.assertEqual(results, None)

        self.mock_request.assert_called_once_with(
            'http://api.example.com'
            payload={'Email': user.email},
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I believe is more clear and straight forward:

```
import unittest

from mock import Mock, patch

import utils

class UtilsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_function(self):
        mock_response = Mock()
        mock_response.status_code = 200
        mock_response.json.return_value = {"UserId": "123456"}
        with patch('utils.requests.get') as mock_requests:
            results = utils.some_function(self.user)
            self.assertEqual(results['UserId'], '123456')
```